# Is the Tcl `file dirname` command usable for URL?

Tags: url, svn, tcl

From a Subversion HTTP URL, I would like to remove some extra files/folders level to get a branch root URL in a Tcl script.

E.g.:

```
http://svn.example.com/repos/trunk/file.tcl
```

-->

```
http://svn.example.com/repos/trunk/
```

---

I tried to use the `file dirname` command but I'm experiencing some *"unexpected behavior"* (at least from my point of view):

```
file dirname {http://svn.example.com/repos/trunk/file.tcl}
```

returns (Windows 7, Tcl 8.5 from an Altera Quartus distribution):

```
http:svn.example.com/repos/trunk
```

**The '`//`' slashes of the URL prefix have been removed!?!**

---

In other Tcl releases (Windows 7, Tcl 8.5 from Cygwin / Linux, Tcl 8.5) I get a different but still incorrect result:

```
http:/svn.example.com/repos/trunk
```

(One '`/`' of the two '`//`' slashes has been removed)

**Why such a result?**

**Is there any alternative?** (apart from using a custom function with `string last`, `string range`...)

---

**Note:** the `file separator` command returns different results depending from the release:

- "`\`" in the Windows *"native"* Tcl from Altera Quartus;
- "`/`" in the Tcl Cygwin / Linux releases.

Answer (score 1):

The `file` command is designed for working with files and filenames, not URLs. This means that it does things (such as removing excess `/` characters) that are *correct* for filenames, but *wrong* for URLs, and this is entirely deliberate.

The [uri package in Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/uri/uri.html) is what you're really looking for, since that lets you extract the path (which *is* filename-like) from a URL so you can manipulate it:

```
package require uri
set uri http://svn.example.com/repos/trunk/file.tcl

# Split a URL up into its components
set uricomponents [uri::split $uri]
# ==> fragment {} port {} path repos/trunk/file.tcl scheme http host svn.example.com query {} pwd {} user {}

# Manipulate the dictionary, in this case to adjust the path part
dict with uricomponents {
    set path [file dirname $path]
}

# Compose back into a normal URL
set newuri [uri::join {*}$uricomponents]
# ==> http://svn.example.com/repos/trunk
```

Yes, `dict with` is ideal for this sort of thing.